# Making ActionBar tabs appear under the content AND integrate a WebView in an ActionBar Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm currently working on an Android application with two ActionBar Tabs.
I have three questions:

1) How can I make the ActionBar Tabs to appear on the bottom of the app (under the fragments)
2) Can I make a WebView in a Navigation drawer (menu)
3) How can I let the ActionBar menu appear on the right side of the ActionBar?

Thanks for answering

EDIT:
With an ActionBar menu, I'm meaning the menu on the middle of this Picture:
http://static.androidnext.de/Facebook-for-Android.jpg

Comment: What is "an ActionBar Menu"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make the ActionBar Tabs to appear on the bottom of the app (under the fragments)

Sorry, that is not possible with action bar tabs. You cannot even control if they show up as tabs at all, let alone their position.

> Can I make a WebView in an ActionBar Menu (the menu for example Facebook has the main Navigation)

What you are referring to is a navigation drawer. Putting a `WebView` in a navigation drawer is technically possible but is unlikely to meet [Google's design guidelines for navigation](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). In your case, given your third question, you presumably are not using this for navigation.

> How can I let the ActionBar menu appear on the right side of the ActionBar?

That depends on what you are using for the navigation drawer. [`DrawerLayout` supports this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html):

> Drawer positioning and layout is controlled using the android:layout_gravity attribute on child views corresponding to which side of the view you want the drawer to emerge from: left or right. (Or start/end on platform versions that support layout direction.)

Comment: thanks that helpful, but does Navigation Drawer support all android versions?

Comment: @Smile2Life: "does Navigation Drawer support all android versions?" -- it works back to API Level 4.